# File exists in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to check file exists in a folder.  I have a test.sh and test.json files in a folder.  In the test.sh file I have scripts for checking whether the test.json file exists. The below code i have used for checking the existance.  I have used the ls command and it shows the file exists but the code I have used is not finding the file and it prints file not exists.

can you pls help me whether I have missed anything here.

```
ls
File=test.json
echo "$FILE"
if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "file exists"
else 
    echo "file not exists"
fi
```

Comment: `FILE` vs `File`

Comment: anubhava3 make that an answer?

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2153) and other common problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` is case sensitive, you need to use same case in declaration and usage.

e.g.

```
FILE=test.json
echo "$FILE"
if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
   ...
```